# accessing elements of one html page in other?

Tags: html

i have a html page called main.html which have a frame frame1 and a text box txt and i am displaying another html page called tree.html in frame1 and i want to access data of text box in tree.html which is shown in frame1 of main.html. is it possible? if yes then how?

Comment: If you need to add more detail to a question, edit it ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244248/accessing-elements-of-one-html-page-in-other ) don't ask a new one.

Comment: I think cross-site scripting might be considered as a security threat

Comment: There's no implication that these pages are on different domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("txt1").value
```

here txt1 is the id of the textbox in the parent page of the iframe.

See [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would suit as you don't say why you're needing to do this but if it's to pass values entered into a textbox to a new page, couldn't you use a [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)?